# SilverStripe 4: Upload multiple images

Tags: gallery, image-uploading, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

This lesson about uploading an image or file is great but what is the latest way in SS4 to upload multiple images at a time. To create a gallery for example with out using GridField.

https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/working-with-files-and-images-1

Does anyone have an example as I'm struggling to convert my old $many_many code.

Comment: I tend to use https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools#bulk-upload for mass image upload. I normally wrap the Image in another dataobject (for title, copyright and other metadata), this is handled as well.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. I got the bulk upload to work. Did you get the versioned config working? Mine is showing a server error when using: https://github.com/colymba/GridFieldBulkEditingTools#versioned. If you have time to show some example code that would be great!

Comment: Try upgrading to 4.1, that changed a bit how unversioned DataObjects can own versioned DataObjects or Files. The upgrade is pretty easy.